# Partial match in a list, from a user input

Tags: list, python-3.x

Trying to get a partial match in a list, from a user input.

I am trying to make a simple diagnostic program. The user inputs their ailment and the program will output a suggested treatment.

```
print("What is wrong with you?")
answer=input()
answer=answer.lower()

problem=""
heat=["temperature","hot"]
cold=["freezing","cold"]

if answer in heat:
    problem="heat"
if answer in cold:
    problem="cold"

print("you have a problem with",problem)
```

I can get it to pick an exact match from the list but I want it to find partial matches from my input. For example if the user types they are "too hot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. The key is the [split()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

```
answer = input('What is wrong with you?')
answer = answer.lower()

heat = ['temperature', 'hot']
cold = ['freezing', 'cold']

for word in answer.split():
    if word in heat:
        problem = 'heat'
    if word in cold:
        problem = 'cold'

print('you have a problem with', problem)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use something like this which might be a bit more "pythonic"

```
answer = input()
cold = ["freezing", "cold"]
if any(answer in c for c in cold):
    problem = "cold"
```